# Ruby: add method to the existing module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, metaprogramming

There is a module:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
  end
end
```

And methods:

```
def add_movie_path
end

def edit_movie_path
end
```

How I can add to module **Routing** this methods?

Is [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-module_exec) only way?

Comment: Simply add then inside module. What's the problem?

Comment: If I could, I would add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    def add_movie_path
    end

    def edit_movie_path
    end
     module_function :edit_movie_path
  end
end
```

So that then you can do a call like it is a **instance method** like so:

```
class Make
   include ActionDispatch::Routing
end 


class MakeAll
   def only_needs_the_one_method
      ActionDispatch::Routing.edit_movie_path
   end
end
```

You can also define it as a **class method** by using `self.class_name` and then directly access it like so:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    def self.add_movie_path
    end

    def self.edit_movie_path
    end
  end
end

class Make
    include ActionDispatch::Routing
   def do_something
     ActionDispatch::Routing.add_movie_path
   end
end 


class MakeAll
   def only_needs_the_one_method
      ActionDispatch::Routing.edit_movie_path
   end
end
```

See that [Modules Magic](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=20194) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand what you're asking, how about something like:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    def add_movie_path
    end

    def edit_movie_path
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could use `module_eval`.

Comment: Is **module_eval** the only way?

Comment: This answer is showing an alternative to `module_eval` which absolutely works.

Comment: simply add a file to config/initalizers with the content above and when rails starts these methods will be available in every objects which includes ActionDispatch::Routing

Comment: And this is not overwrite existing module? Only expand?

Comment: Exactly.  Extending functionality is what meta-programming is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your methods inside the module.

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    def add_movie_path
    end

    def edit_movie_path
    end  
  end
end
```